# Uploading a website to a server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, webserver, localhost, server-side

Usually when you have xampp, wamp and lamp your php files and databases are stored on your local machine and not the actual server so how would you move a finished project with its database from localhost to your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create zip file of your project and upload it to our server an then extract it there. And export your database, then sql file is created. Create database on server and import that sql file in that database. And change database connection settings. Create user with username and password on server database and provide that details in your connection settings.

Comment: Might be obvious but usually you do the upload using FTP if you're on a shared host. There's no need to zip the files. The transfer will be faster, but your hoster might not allow to run programs, which you have to to unzip your files again.

Comment: I just wish to transfer 543mb of data so would that be slowm

Comment: it depend on your net speed..have you uploaded your site to server successfully?

Comment: Yeah I've tried and it is currently uploading 16 mins left...